# how do I add this Javascript to my wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have something put together on codepen that I want to add to my wordpress site. I am currently developing locally and I can't seem to get the javascript to work. Yes, I read on the codex that you have to register and then enqueue the script. That doesnt work for me....unless I'm missing something. I even tried just putting the script in my header, but that didnt work either. I'm a bit lost and would appreciate some help....its working in codepen fine.

what I want to add: http://codepen.io/figaro/pen/jPqPGG

```
$(function() {
```

var srcURL = "http://roostergrin.com";
    $("iframe").attr("src", srcURL);

});

I've got the HTML and CSS working, but how do I get the script to work?

Comment: Are you linking to the jQuery library? This isn't using pure javascript, this is using a javascript library `jQuery` and for you to use those pre-built functions you will need to link to the library.

Comment: Ok, ill admit I'm pretty new at this. I totally forgot about that...used to it being plugged in by default in codepen. well...haha thanks, i feel stupid but I get it now

Comment: It's a simple mistake to make. **Tip:** when working with javascript, the browser console is your best friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframes src's are being set, I can only assume you aren't linking to the jQuery library

If you open your browser console you might see this message.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you cannot link to the jQuery library for whatever given reason, here's a pure javascript method

```
window.onload=function(){
    var frames=document.getElementsByClassName('devices')[0].getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for(var i=0; i<frames.length; i++){
        frames[i].setAttribute('src','http://roostergrin.com');
    }
}
```

If you have any questions about, please leave a comment below and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Comment: awesome, thank you so much. I did forget to link to the JQuery library and I really appreciate you showing me the pure javascript method, I didn't know how to do that.

Comment: Very welcome! If you don't understand anything from the method here I will be more than happy to update the post and explain it.